# 4 Attempts to Guess a Number Between 1-15

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Is there a way to find a number between 1-15 in 4 attempts? In each attempt you can guess a range / combination of numbers and you will get an answer if the number is in that range / combination or not.  You are not allowed to ask directly which number it is. Only whole numbers are involved.

Comment: You might want to define your objective for your question such as "Is there a way to ensure you will get the correct number"

Comment: What do you mean by combination of numbers?

Comment: @Duck Let's say: is it a number from 1-8? Is it one of the even numbers?...

Comment: It looks like as long as you're splitting the numbers in half in each question you will eventually gets the answer without tricks.  Or, see Chris's answer for Mystery tricks~

Comment: Yes, binary search.

Comment: In a binary representation, $x$ between $0$ and $15=2^4-1$ has four digits.

Comment: Just for fun: It can be done in only 3 guesses if you allow asking "yes or no" questions (hint: the third answer to a "yes or no question" would be "I do not know" when answering either "yes" or "no" is impossible due to unknown information or a paradox).

Comment: It is presumed you mean integers or natural numbers, so you might want to state that.

Comment: A significantly more interesting question _(which leads to even deeper Comp Sci theory)_ is, what if the answerer is allowed to lie up to `L` times?

Answer (score 73):

Yes.
Guess 1st set (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15) -> If the number is in the set, write down 1
Guess 2nd set (2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15) -> If the number is in the set, write down 2
Guess 3rd set (4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15) -> If the number is in the set, write down 4
Guess 4th set (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) -> If the number is in the set, write down 8

After all 4 guesses, add the numbers you wrote down.  This will be the chosen number.
1 Appears in Set 1 only, so you will have written down 1
12 appears in Sets 3 and 4 only, so you will have written down 4 + 8 = 12.
15 appears in all Sets, so you will have written down 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15.

This works based on the binary representation of numbers, that is, every number can be written as a sum of powers of 2 - {1,2,4,8,16,32,... 2<sup>n</sup>)

[image: Table comparing the Binary values of 1 (0001) through 15 (1111) against the Binary values of 1, 2, 4 and 8 (0001, 0010, 0100, and 1000)]

Homework:  Can you do a number between 1 and 31 in 5 questions?

See [Mystery Calculator Trick](https://mathsedideas.blogspot.com/2017/12/on-christmas-cracker-mystery-calculator.html)

Comment: Thank you! but I'm actually a middel school student so I have no idea what yu are saying :D Can you please explain this more easily?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes it is much better but but how did you come to this solution?

Comment: Can you please help me to do this with 1.000 numbers?

Comment: This is basically a binary search. Each "level" of items (1, 2, 4, and 8) is a list of numbers that have that bit set in  a binary representation of that number.

Comment: @JongeRoge is this a homework question?

Comment: Is there any advantage using this method instead of @WeatherVane's binary search? This just seam unnecessarily hard (for a human that is, may be easier for a computer)

Comment: @Gilsido, Each of the questions is effectively asking for one of the digits of the binary representation of the number, so it only requires a understanding of binary, which isn't difficult for humans to understand. It does require more work than a binary search, though.

Comment: Re "*Can you do a number between 1 and 31 in 5 questions?*", I can do 0..31 in 5 questions :)

Comment: @ikegami: I can do 1...32 in 5 questions ;)

Comment: @Adriano, The point I was making was the method works for 32 items, not merely 31. In fact, one can use the method for *any* 32 items, not just numbers, and including non-sequential numbers. One does so by mapping each item to a number in 0..31. (Well, it technically works for 0+c..31+c, as you suggest.)

Comment: There is a variant to this puzzle that's known as "Poison" which asks you to identify a single vial of poison out of 1,000 with 10 test strips. The way that the puzzle is worded leads the solver towards Binary search; however it's important to realize that this method is not binary search because this test can be performed independent of the data set (read: can be done in parallel). The number of tests required is the strict log_2(y) = x where y is the number of "things" in your testable set and x is the number of tests required.

Comment: @Kat No it is for myself trying to understand binary numbers :)

Comment: Haha I'll do the homework :)

Comment: @Gilsido If the question was worded such that you had to ask all 4 questions **at the same time** (or in pairs), then you can't use a Binary Search.  Taking the "Poison" example - if it takes you 8 hours to determine if a sample contains Poison, but you only have 24 hours to work out which one of the King's 31 bottles of wine is poisoned before his guests arrive, then this method is superior!  You can work it out in 8 hours instead of needing 32

Comment: I can guess which number you're thinking about between 1-1000000 with only one question and few sentences, and the question is can you think about one number between 1 - 1 000 000?

Answer (score 55):

A simple way is to pick the number $X$ which is half-way through the range and ask

> Is it less than $X$?

From the answer you can discard either the lower half or the upper half of the range.

Repeat until you have 1 number left.

This [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is known as a **binary search** or **binary chop**.

---

In general, If you are allowed $q$ queries, you can get an answer from $2^q$ items. Here you have $4$ guesses, so you can succeed when there are $16$ or fewer items.

From the other way round, if you have $n$ items, you need $log_2 n$ guesses (rounded up).

The numbers *do not need to be consecutive*: just split the group into two equal size parts (or off by 1 if an odd number) and eliminate one half.

Comment: To generalize your answer you could add that any number X with 0 <= X < 2^n can be guessed in n attempts. It would also answer [all the similar questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91518/10-attempts-to-guess-a-number-between-1-1000)

Comment: @Fabich it doesn't have to be a power of two to work, but that is the limit.

Comment: In practice, this is the simplest and most straightforward way to achieve it. Hands down. +1

Answer (score 24):

To build off @ChrisCudmore’s correct answer (go upvote it!), here is the same answer but with a simpler less technical explanation – hopefully this will be easier to understand…

> All the whole numbers 1-15 can be calculated by adding some or all of the numbers 1, 2, 4 and 8, like so:
>
>  **1** = 1
>  **2** = 2
>  **3** = 1 + 2
>  **4** = 4
>  **5** = 1 + 4
>  **6** = 2 + 4
>  **7** = 1 + 2 + 4
>  **8** = 8
>  **9** = 1 + 8
>  **10** = 2 + 8
>  **11** = 1 + 2 + 8
>  **12** = 4 + 8
>  **13** = 1 + 4 + 8
>  **14** = 2 + 4 + 8
>  **15** = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8

If you are allowed to ask four questions before then saying which number it is, you should use the following 4 questions:

> 1. Is it one of {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15} – or more simply, “Is it an odd number?”
>  2. Is it one of {2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15}?
>  3. Is it one of {4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15}?
>  4. Is it one of {8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} – or more simply, “Is it higher than 7?”
>
>  (The trick here is that all of the numbers mentioned in Question 1 need a '1' in their sum, all of those in Question 2 need a '2' in their sum, all of those in Question 3 need a '4' in their sum, and all of those in Question 4 need an '8' in their sum - compare them to the list above, and see for yourself.)

Now to find the number, start with 0.

> If the answer to Question 1 was ‘Yes’, **add 1**; if ‘No’, do nothing.
>
>  If the answer to Question 2 was ‘Yes’, **add 2**; if ‘No’, do nothing.
>
>  If the answer to Question 3 was ‘Yes’, **add 4**; if ‘No’, do nothing.
>
>  If the answer to Question 4 was ‘Yes’, **add 8**; if ‘No’, do nothing.
>
>  *The result of adding these up will be the number the other person was thinking of!*

You will **always** get the correct answer here – try it and see :)

Comment: Nice.  Rewrote mine in similar way to make it age appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Brill - love your 'Homework' line! :)

Comment: Its good pedagogy... Give a solution and ask them to extend it.

Comment: Thank you very much! But why did you choose these combinations? What is the explanation behind it?

Comment: @JongeRoge Just added a line to the second block above - take a look now :)

Comment: @Stiv You are amazing! Thank you very much! Can I also do this with 1-1000 numbers?

Comment: @JongeRoge Yes, in fact you can do all of 1-1023 with 10 questions in a similar way! Try ChrisCudmore's suggestion of 1-31 with 5 questions first (since that's simpler) and you should be able to spot the pattern that will enable you to expand this for bigger and bigger numbers :) Good luck!

Comment: @Stiv Thank you! But do I have to always write all sum of numbers? Even if I want to go till 1023?

Comment: @JongeRoge This is where ChrisCudmore's original explanation about binary numbers becomes incredibly useful - for higher and higher numbers it quickly becomes impractical to write out every number as a sum... But if you can study a little bit about binary numbers ([this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-number-system.html) is quite a nice introduction) it gives you a shortcut... (You end up asking "If I wrote the number in binary, would there be a '1' in *this* position?", for each of the different digits... and amazingly that works out as the same question as in our explanations here!)

Comment: @Stiv Thank you very much! I will read it and I will come back to tell you if I understood.

Comment: @JongeRoge In case you're not aware - binary number is used for each of the 'base' group - 1,2,4,8 (and 16,32,64, 128 and so on) to making it easier to create all those grouping. So, with Chris's origin answer, 1 = 0001, 2 = 0010, 4 = 0100... would make more sense to you now.

Comment: @Stiv  Thank you both very much! Let's say we go till 1000. 
Guess 1st set (1,3,…1000) 
Guess 2nd set (2,3,…1000) 
Guess 3rd set (4,5,…1000) 
Guess 4th set (8,9,…1000) 
Guess 5th set (16,17…1000
Guess 6th set (32,33,…1000)
Guess 7th set (64,65,…1000)
Guess 8th set (128,129,…1000)
Guess 9th set (256,257,…1000)
Guess 10th set (489,490,…1000)
Is this correct? But how can I then find like the number 492?

Comment: @Stiv Can you please help me to do this with 1.000 numbers?

Comment: @JongeRoge The trick is to work out what powers of 2 you need. Which numbers out of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 and 512 do you need to add to get 492? Ignore 512 (too large) and the other numbers would ALL add to 511 (that's their sum). Take off 19 to get 492 i.e. exclude 1, 2 and 16 (which sum to 19) and you get 492 = 4 + 8 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256. In binary you would write 492 as 111101100 - read from the right: 0 1's + 0 2's + 1 x 4 + 1 × 8 + 0 16's + 1 x 32 + 1 x 64 + 1 x 128 + 1 x 256. Bingo!

Comment: @JongeRoge You should also check out [WeatherVane's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91514/60644) for a simple technique. ChrisCudmore and I have focused on explaining binary but WeatherVane's answer is wonderfully straightforward... :)

Comment: Very nice explanation if a very nice algorithm!

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by splitting the range in half. If the numbers to guess from (1-16) is less than 2^X where x is the number of guesses you get. Look at the picture below, and each color is 1 guess:

[image: Step down through the guesses]

Hypothetically, the answer is 16 (I rounded up to split the numbers easier). 
1. you guess 1-8, and that isn't it
2. you guess 9-12 and that isn't it
3. you guess 13-14 and that isn't it
4. you guess 15 and that isn't it.

In 4 guesses you were able to halve the numbers till you are down to 1.

This game also works if you can select only 1 number, and you are told whether it is higher or lower. In that case, you half the range with each guess.

Comment: This is actually a simpler answer.  Upvote it.

Comment: My picture got deleted :( it illustrates the point pretty well.

Comment: Isn't this the same as @WeatherVane 's answer?

Comment: I'm confused about the correct steps when the range *does* contain the correct number. Assume the correct answer, or number, is 5. Then, following  your steps: 1.) *Guess range [1-8]; 2.) Answer is Yes; 3.) Split range [1-8] into [1-4] and [5-8] to check halves; 4.) Question: Ask if correct number is in [1-4] or [5-8]? Not sure... 5.) **Worst case scenario would be, * guess [1-4]; 6.) Since 5 is not in [1-4], you get a no; 7.) Split the rest of the correct range [5-8]: [5-6] and [7-8]; 8.) Now * Guess [5-6]; 9.) This leaves one guess.  If we can, we can ask if it's the 6, which points at the 5

Answer (score 2):

So I can’t comment since I don’t have enough reputation yet. I just want to say that this is the coolest thing I have ever seen. I had no idea that binary could be used in such a way that you could guess a number in a certain amount of guesses 100% of the time as long as the amount of guesses was equal to the amount of digits in binary of the highest number in the range!

**How Our Number System Works**
Binary is another way to represent a number. Our number system is in base 10, since each digit/place is in base 10. Example: the number 295 has a 5 in the 1s place (the ones place is represented by base 10 as $10^0$), a 9 in the 10’s place (the tens place is represented as $10^1$) and a 2 in the hundreds place (hundreds place is $10^2$). Notice that our normal number system is in base 10 which means the first digit “place” is 10 with exponent 0 which make it 1 (the ones place), following places are just powers of 10.

**How Binary Works** Binary on the other hand, uses a base 2 number system. In other words, the bases are 2, and the digit place is a power of 2. Binary uses only 0’s and 1’s since the digit places are only a power of 2. If it is base 10, you need 10 digits, binary is base 2 so 2 digits are used. Binary has a ones,($2^0$) twos($2^1$), fours($2^2$), eights($2^3$) instead of ones, tens, hundreds places from our number system. If you had 21 in base 10 (our system), and you wanted to convert it to binary, you would take the highest power of 2 you can out of 21, then represent the rest as binary until you are left with nothing (I will show you that). The highest power of 2 that you can take out of 21 is $2^4$ which is 16. So the binary for 21 would have a highest place of $2^4$(sixteens place). Once you take 16 out of 21, you are left with 5. Once again, take out the highest power of 2 you can out of what you have left (5). The highest power of 2 you can take out of 5 is $2^2$ which is 4. Once you take 4 out of 5, you are left with 1. Again, subtract the highest power of 2 you can out of 1. The highest power of 2 you can take out of 1 is $2^0$ which is 1. Once you have done that, you are left with nothing so you are done figuring out how you will structure 21 in binary.
Since you subtracted out $2^4$, the number in the $2^4$ is 1, since you had to subtract $2^4$ out of 21 1 time. The next place in binary is $2^3$ which is 8. You never subtracted 8 from 21, so a 0 will go there. Next place in binary is $2^2$ which is 4. You did take 4 out of 21 after you took 16 out of 21, so a 1 will go in the $2^2$s place. Next place is $2^1$s place(equals 2), and you never took 2 out of 21, so a 0 will go there. Last place in binary is the $2^0$s place which is the ones place. You did take 1 out of 21 so a 1 goes in that place. Your final result will be 10101 representing one 1, 0 twos, 1 four, 0 eights, and 1 sixteens. Notice that 1+4+16 equals 21.

Incase you were wondering, this is where the 1’s and 0’s came from in @Chris Cudmore’s original answer.

Comment: This is one of the first algorithms you learn when you get a math degree.  I use it about once a month to search through MILLIONS of records by hand.  Takes about 20 minutes.

Comment: Very interesting, how do you use it for searching through records efficiently?

Comment: Suppose we have a list of a million records, and we want to find the *last* one before a change happened (like, the last record to use a kind of form, for example).  To do that, start in the middle.  If it changed, eliminate the upper half.  If it didn't, eliminate the lower half.  Continue in this way until there is only one left.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

At least not unless you put up more restrictions. E.g. that the numbers have to be integers.

None of the solutions shown so far give a way to find $\sqrt \pi$ , which is between 1-15.

If you restrict yourself to integers you can use this method:

```
sum = 0
s = 1
while s <= max value:
  Ask: "Is the number odd?"
  Yes: Add s to sum
       Subtract 1 from number
  Tell the person to divide number by 2
  Double s
sum is now the correct number
```

Or as a program:

```
sum = 0
s = 1
while s <= maxvalue:
  if number % 2 == 1:
    sum = sum + s
    number = number - 1
  number = number / 2
  s = s + s
print sum
```

Try using that to guess a number between 1 and 1023. How many guesses did that take?

Comment: It's a bit pedantic, but you haven't shown that your program always terminates after 4 guesses.

Comment: Number is divided by 2 in each round which means it terminates after log2(number) rounds. log2(16) = 4, so log2(15) < 4. QED.

Comment: In the question,  it's stated,  unless I'm mistaken,  that only whole numbers are allowed.  Since whole numbers are positive integers, whole numbers are an even greater restriction than just "integers" would be.

Comment: @JamieWatts That restriction was added by Cotton Headed Ninnymuggins in an edit after my first answer. Whether that is what OP meant is unknown.

Comment: @OleTange Sorry about my comment, then. I thought maybe you didn't see the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with  trying to eliminate half of the numbers between 1-15

**1st problem:** you eventually narrow it down to 2 numbers at which point you have to ask about 1 specific number which isn’t allowed.

**2nd problem:** if the questions aren’t answered when they’re asked, but rather all 4 questions are answered after they’re *all* asked, then eliminating half wouldn’t work. Using binary (@Chris Cudmore) to use ranges of numbers works the best since each question isn’t dependent on the previous.

As @Ole Tange said, there needs to be more restrictions like only whole numbers, and the 4 questions are answered only after they’re all asked, eliminating the possibility of depending on each answer to formulate another question. In other words, should the 4 questions asked **all** be determined **before** asking them, or can they be formulated on the fly?

Comment: The first problem is a non-problem.  Suppose I've narrowed it down to either 3 or 4.  Then I can ask, "Is the number strictly less than 4?" or "Is it in the set {2, 3}?".  This is a trivial transformation from asking whether it's a particular number.  Mind you, the constraint about asking directly if it's a specific number adds no value to the problem anyway.